# select statment that has columns made from different rows of a joined table

Tags: sql

2 tables

user cols = name,email

```
joe|joe@gmail.com
sara|sara@hotmail.com
alan|alan@gmail.com
```

table 2 is extras cols = name,col,value

```
joe|favoritecolor|blue
joe|boss|sam
sara|favoritecolor|green
```

(really extending the schema of the first table but not so that the sql engine notices it)

To get peoples favoritecolor

```
Select  name
      , value As favoritecolor
From    user
      , extras
Where   extras.name = user.name
        And extras.col = 'favoritecolor'
```

But how do I get favoritecolor and boss?

Note the output I want for this query

```
select name,email,favoritecolor,boss from user
```

is

```
joe|joe@gmail|blue|sam
sara|sara@hotmail.com|green|<null>
alan|alan@gmail.com|<null>|<null>
```

Comment: With an extra join

Comment: can you show the syntax please, as an asnwer so I get accept it

Comment: Two other beat me to an answer, and theirs is better SQL than what I had in mind. Btw: Your `extras` table looks suspiciously like a triple store, maybe you should look into RDF.

Comment: @sentry - whats RDF - point me at it pls

Comment: RDF Resource Description Framework,  https://www.w3.org/2003/01/21-RDF-RDB-access/

Comment: In a nutshell: RDF stores everything as graph and you can represent that graph as collection of triples (subject predicate object), which is what your `extras` table looks like

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use double join on the same table using alias

(for join use inner join if the keys always are present and match otherwise use left join)

```
 select a.name, e1.value  as favoritecolor , e2.value as boss
 from user
 INNER JOIN extras as e1 on e1.name = user.name and e1.col = 'favoritecolor'
 INNER JOIN extras as e2 on e2.name = user.name and e2.col = 'boss'
```

If your col don't match always you should use left join

```
 select a.name, e1.value  as favoritecolor , e2.value as boss
 from user
 left JOIN extras as e1 on e1.name = user.name and e1.col = 'favoritecolor'
 left JOIN extras as e2 on e2.name = user.name and e2.col = 'boss'
```

if you have always a favorite color relation but not always a boss

```
 select a.name, e1.value  as favoritecolor , e2.value as boss
 from user
 Inner JOIN extras as e1 on e1.name = user.name and e1.col = 'favoritecolor'
 left JOIN extras as e2 on e2.name = user.name and e2.col = 'boss'
```

Comment: except I just found that this doesnt work for sara, she has no boss so i end up with no output. I want her to have <null> for boss

Comment: @pm100   as in my answer  if you don't match always  you should use left jojn  .( i don't know you real data and condition) .anyway i have update the answer with this code too ..this  work also when some col don't match

Comment: left join gives me only rows from main table that have data in the second table

Comment: got it working - i missed the left join for each col - ty

Comment: @pm100   . well .. I had added in the introduction because I know that can cause these problems .. I hope everything works    and you have now clear  the concept

Answer (score 2):

First, learn to use proper `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

You can do what you want with multiple joins:

```
select u.name, efc.value as favoritecolor,
       eb.value as boss
from user u left join
     extras efc
     on efc.name = u.name and efc.col = 'favoritecolor' left join
     extras eb
     on eb.name = u.name and eb.col = 'boss';
```

The `left join` is needed to be sure that rows are not filtered just because they are missing a particular value.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   b.name    AS ExtraName,
   b.col     AS ExtraCol,
   b.value   AS ExtraValue,
   a.name    AS UserName,
   a.email   AS UserEmail
FROM User A INNER JOIN Extras B ON B.name = A.name
WHERE B.col = 'favorite color' AND b.value = 'Boss'
```

Comment: this is very different form the other answers, is it correct?

Comment: The queries will not return the same thing.  The question is a bit vague.  the asker needs to determine which is correct.  This is my attempt at making sense of the question but I may not have interpreted it correctly.  Question phrasing is a bit confusing.

Comment: I want one row for each user row. I want favoritecolor and boss to be columns on that one row

Comment: This should do that.  But there are ways of interpreting that differently.  Try this and you decide if this works.  It will depend on how your data is loaded on if this is correct or not.

Comment: My query properly for Sql joins the two tables and filters to just the Favorite Color and Boss values if that is what you seek.

Comment: i updated the question to show the output i an trying to get

Comment: What I am trying to get at is the question is not that specific.  My query works with the join provided.  If the column called col is where you look for Favorite Color this is correct.  But it will depend on capitalizations possibly.  May find "favorite color" but not find "Favorite Color".  If value is where "Boss" is desired again it will work if your data is stored as "Boss" and not "boss" depending on the configuration of your server on if it is case sensitive.

Comment: Sql is an extremely specific language, it has to be.  The question is not that specific.  You have to try this query with your data and see if it gives you what you seek.  If this is some sort of lab question then the answer is good enough for this purpose.  Do you actually have two tables of data?  Can you run this query on the data and see if it works?